# Tensorflow Android - Ops can be multi-threaded but with multi-threaded application?

Tags: tensorflow

As per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tfmobile/optimizing#threading), ops can be multi-threaded on mobile (default `inter_op_parallelism_threads` is set to `1`) based on the number of cores on that particular device. I am building an Android application that has three concurrent (threads) running three different models, would it be possible to still enable `inter_op_parallelism_threads` and set to `4` for a quad-core device?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to mobile,  `inter_op_parallelism_threads` is not big of use, but based on the documentation, there is a significant benefit from number of threads with in the operation (**"intra"** - not inter). And the variable to be used for it is `intra_op_parallelism_threads`.

> On mobile, how many threads an op will use is set to the number of
>   cores by default, or 2 when the number of cores can't be determined.
>   You can override the default number of threads that ops are using by
>   setting intra_op_parallelism_threads in the session options

Comment: You must presume that i have read the documentation that i shared.

Comment: My intention is, even though you are able to set 4 to that parameter, there is no benefit that you may notice.